# How to destroy Zend_Session_Namespace without session_destroy

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-session

I store a couple of value in a temporary session using: `$job = new Zend_Session_Namespace('application');`

How would I destroy only the session **application** without clearing all sessions.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To remove a value from a session, use PHP's unset() function on the object property.
Let's say $job has a property 'username' like so :

```
$job = new Zend_Session_Namespace('application');
$job->username = 'test';
```

To remove username from the session just do :

```
unset($job->username);
```

To remove the whole 'application' namespace and asociated data you can use :

```
Zend_Session::namespaceUnset('application');
```