# Error on Zend_Session::namespaceUnset('Default');

Tags: zend-framework, session

I'm fairly new to Zend and I think this question won't be so hard to answer.

I'd like to unset my entire session namespace (called 'Default'), and I've found a possible answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053461/how-to-destroy-zend-session-namespace-with-session-destroy), but when I use the following line of code `Zend_Session::namespaceUnset('Default');` I get this error: `Zend_Session is currently marked as read-only.`

Hopefully someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is set to read-only, then you can remove the read-only, by called

`$namespace->unlock();`

Also, "Default" is the **default** namespace name. I always change this to something else. You can also check if the $namespace you are trying to use is locked by using:

`$namespace->isLocked()`. This will return a boolean true/false of the status of the namespace.

So... what you might have is this (from [docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.advanced_usage.html)):

```
$userProfileNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('userProfileNamespace');

// marking session as read only locked
$userProfileNamespace->lock();

// unlocking read-only lock
if ($userProfileNamespace->isLocked()) {
    $userProfileNamespace->unLock();
}
```